# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Bidirectional mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Hi I have a problem with JPA...

DB:

[image: Database]

Java classes (irrelevant fields are ommited):

User:

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    private int iduser;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserInfo
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade= {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserInfo> userInfos;
}
```

UserInfo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_info")
public class UserInfo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="iduser_info")
    private int iduserInfo;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne  
    private User user;
}
```

Currently when I try to do this (again I omitted setting irrelevant fields):

```
User u = new User();            
UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
u.addUserInfo(info);

em.persist(u); // save user
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webstore`.`user_info`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_info_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_iduser`) REFERENCES `user` (`iduser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I have been banging my head all day and I can't figure it out... I have also searched for solutions here but they all suggest that this error shows that I want to enter UserInfo without user_iduser value entered, but even if I add this before persist:

```
info.setUser(u);
```

it still doesn't work - is bidirectional mapping even supported with cascading? The desired effect is that User should be inserted and then all the UserInfos in the list after it refering the original User. How can I achieve that?

I don't want to do

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0/1;
```

everytime =(

Comment: Before you persist, have you tried setting a reference on the UserInfo instance to the User. Something like info.setUser(u)?

Comment: I have tried that see after the error part in my question =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_iduser", nullable=false)
private User user;
```

Then see if this works. I'm assuming that in `user_info` table, the `user_id` field is `NOT NULL` in your RDBMS. Also, since it's bidirectional, you will have to `setXXX` on `UserInfo` and `User`.

```
User u = new User();            
UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
info.setUser(u);
u.addUserInfo(info);

em.persist(u); // save user
```

---

**Update:** Are you sure you're specifying an ID for both `User` and `UserInfo`? It looks like the ID is not set hence there is no reference to link `UserInfo` to `User`.

If the ID are `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then add the following after `@Id` annotation:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: I added 

    @JoinColumn(name="user_iduser", nullable=false) ( user_id was producing an error user_iduser was ok) before
    private User user; in UserInfo

and:

    info.setUser(u);

before persist and still the same error.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the error. The name is `user_iduser`. Does my solution work now?

Comment: I have added both parts - in my UserInfo and in BL class but still no go :(

and yes user_info.user_iduser is NOT NULL

Comment: Yes now it works =) Wow - I generated entities with Jboss Tools and I guess I missed that Identity part. Thank you=)

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. That's why I write my code completely on my own. That way, I get to actually map my classes to its relevant tables. :-)

Comment: Yea I will do it from now on too =) Thank you again - It's unimaginable how such a small mistake can ruin your day.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this error, fixed this error by adding `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotation on top of iduser and you must have foreign keys CASCADE ON DELETE, UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me in my example ,
i created books and library.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Books{ 
        @Id
        private int library_id;
        private String libraryname;

        //add getters and setters bellow
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "library")
public class Book {
        @Id
        private int book_id;
        private String book_title;

        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="library_id" , nullable = false)
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private Library library;

       //set getters and setters
 }
```

in controller i used this method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{libraryId}/book", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Book createBook(@PathVariable(value = "libraryId") Integer libraryId, @RequestBody Book book) {

        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        Library author1 = new Library();

        Optional<Library> byId = LibraryRepository.findById(libraryId);


        Library author = byId.get();

        book.setLibrary(author);

        Book book1 = bookRepository.save(book);
        books.add(book1);
        author1.setBooks((List<Book>) books);

        return book1;
}
```